# Bash here document produces no output, any idea why?

Tags: bash, echo, eof

On my Acer 725 with Lubuntu 13.04 this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "======"
echo <<xxxxx
aaaaaaaaaqqqqqqqqq
xxxxx
echo "======"
```

produces this output:

```
======

======
```

It should produce this:

```
======
aaaaaaaaaqqqqqqqqq
======
```

I've searched all over for a reason but I can't find anything.  I have a horrible feeling that I am missing something embarrassingly obvious.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well I was right about something at least; it was embarrassingly obvious.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a horrible feeling that I am missing something embarrassingly
>   obvious.

Use `cat` instead of `echo`:

```
cat <<xxxxx
aaaaaaaaaqqqqqqqqq
xxxxx
```

Answer (score 10):

Heredocs send the content to stdin. `echo` doesn't read from stdin.